# How to set "conditional formatting" for the colors of a graphic in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, charts, google-sheets, google-visualization

I need to set the colors of a graphic in the function of a condition. To be more specific: I have a Pie Chart and I need to set the color of each piece of the Pie (red of blue) in the function of a parameter that will change.

So far, the only option that I have found is the automatic color selection for each piece of the Pie. I can also define manually the color of each piece (red or green), but still, I don't see any option to set this color in a conditional way.

This is more or less what I have, so far:

[image: https://infoinspired.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/finished-pie-chart.jpg]

With the conditional formatting, I want to have something like that:

[image: https://singvestor.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/2014-08-Bloomberg-chart-details.jpg]

(Reds and greens are assigned conditionally and automatically)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @player0 !!! Now it's a bit easier to understand my case.

Comment: this won't be possible without script